# Why is the location of this script changing the behaviour of webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, addeventlistener

A small Javascript function to capitalize the contents of a text fields is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>capitalize</title>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="uname" length="20" /><br />
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
<script>
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click",eve);
function eve(){
    var uname = document.getElementById("uname").value; 
    uname = uname.toUpperCase();
    document.getElementById("uname").value=uname;
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Now, this is working normally, but when I change the location of the Javascript code to ***head*** tag, it's not working.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>key events</title>
<script>
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click",eve);
function eve(){
    var uname = document.getElementById("uname").value; 
    uname = uname.toUpperCase();
    document.getElementById("uname").value=uname;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="uname" length="20" /><br />
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a document.ready function.

When you put the code before closing the body tag, the DOM has been completely created.
Different case when you put it inside the head tag

Answer (score 1):

Scripts located within the head are executed before the body has been rendered. So the elements you're trying to target don't exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping `js` referencing element within `window.onload` event handler where `js` is within `head` element; as the `#submit` element is not loaded into `DOM` when `.addEventListener` attached to `document.getElementById("submit")`

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>key events</title>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", eve);

      function eve() {
        var uname = document.getElementById("uname").value;
        uname = uname.toUpperCase();
        document.getElementById("uname").value = uname;
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="uname" length="20" />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When in the head, your script executes before the rest of the page is loaded. Make sure you wait for your page to be loaded :

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click",eve);
    function eve(){
        var uname = document.getElementById("uname").value; 
        uname = uname.toUpperCase();
        document.getElementById("uname").value=uname;
    }    
}
```